# Can you wash your feet without making them temporarily adhesive?

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science, surface-tension, liquid-state

When my feet get dirty I wash them in the shower but then when I walk around the house small particles on the floor get glued to my feet which I don't like.

Boring solutions would be to use a towel or vacuum the floor more often but from a physics perspective this is happening because of surface tension right?

Is there a liquid that has significantly lower surface tension with air at STP than water and evaporates at a similar rate?

To be used for hygiene it would also need to be medically safe but let us ignore that for now.

Comment: I don't think this is (just) surface tension but the skin itself gets more sticky. Even when you dry off the liquid water with a towel, you still pick up dirt quickly. The skin absorbs the water and becomes softer and thicker, and there's probably also fatty oils from the skin.

Answer (score 0):

The liquid disinfectant everybody uses during COVID epidemic is a liquid which does what you want, after some time so you feet lack fat
and it evaporates faster than water.

Answer (score 0):

One trick is to wash your feet with diethyl ether. It has a boiling point of around 36 degrees Celsius, and quickly evaporates even in room temperature. It is relatively non-toxic (similar to ethanol), but poses a fire hazard because it is extremely flammable so be careful.